# Stop RS from executing dataset if Date Validation Fails

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following code which checks the date range selected in my report

```
Function ValidateDateRange(StartDate as DateTime , EndDate as DateTime) as Boolean
Dim RetValue As Boolean
RetValue = "False"
if(DateDiff("m",StartDate,EndDate)>3) Then
    RetValue = "False"
Else
    RetValue = "True"
End if
Return RetValue
End Function`
```

I've created a hidden parameter called "ValidateDate" and assigned this code to the Default Values as an expression

```
=Code.ValidateDateRange(Parameters!DateFrom.Value, Parameters!DateTo.Value)
```

I have a text box which displays the message

"*Date range selected must be less than 3 months*"

and the Visibility property is set to this hidden variable.

So far this lot works

However, when the report is run with a date range of greater than 3 months selected, the text box appears but the data set still executes retrieving the data (stored procedure).

Is there a way to stop RS from executing the dataset when the date range validation fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely need to add a similar validation to your stored procedure.  Something like the following should work.

```
IF DATEDIFF(month, @startDate, @endDate) <= 3
   BEGIN
   [your stored procedure here]
   END
```